# How to play videos sequentially in iOS - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, xcode4.5

I have a default media player, i want to play videos one by one sequentially. how do i do it?
Any easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add observer in `MPMoviePlayer` for `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:yourMPMoviePlayerObject];

-(void)myMovieFinished:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [aNotification object];
    //maintain index of video in this method as each time video URL will be different
    [moviePlayer setContentURL:nextVideoURLhere];
    [moviePlayer play];
}
```

Remove when not required:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidFinishNotification object:yourMPMoviePlayerObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain an array which is containing all the videos list has to play . First assign on song to the player after completion of the song you can call like this . This is an example only .

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged) 
    name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

Then in that method release the previous player and alloc the new player with the new song.Repeat the same for the all .